# Style Prime-ng dropdown child elements

Tags: css, primeng

I am trying to style elements within a prime-ng dropdown. These styles are child element found within the  tag and I am not sure how to access them. Here is the code, I have taken out what is not relevant.

```
<p-dropdown _ngcontent-c12="" id="src" placeholder="Please select" class="ng-tns-c19-2 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ui-inputwrapper-filled" ng-reflect-placeholder="Please select" ng-reflect-options="[object Object],[object Object" ng-reflect-model="4">
    <div class="ng-tns-c19-2 ui-dropdown ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" style="width: 246px;">
    </div>
</p-dropdown>
```

I am trying to style the  inside of the  element. I only see the  in my browser but not in my HTML code. The div inherently gets created when the  is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `p-dropdown` selector with `::ng-deep` and after the class/selector you want to style

For example to set color to content of list:

```
p-dropdown ::ng-deep  .mat-list-item-content{
  color:red;
}
```

[See example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-jtxppf?file=app/app.component.css)

Comment: tell me for more help